# Why does ipa-getkeytab fail on samba server?

Tags: samba, freeipa

I am not a systems person, please forgive my lack of knowledge.

I have set up FreeIPA 4.5 on Centos 7. I was able to successfully manage user login to a test server (Fedora 27). So, FreeIPA is "working" (in that capacity anyway).

I am trying to use FreeIPA to manage access rights for a Samba server (again, Fedora 27), in a test environment for now. I am following instructions on the FreeIPA site.

So far I have added the service to the ipa server via `ipa service-add cifs/sambatest.my.realm` (with my working domain). However, I had to use --force because DNS failed (I know this is possibly related, I could not get past this issue either). 
When I try to `ipa-getkeytab -s ipaserver.my.realm -p cifs/sambatest.my.realm -k /etc/samba/samba.keytab` on the Samba server, I get `Failed to add key to the keytab`

Can anyone give me some guidance? Please let me know of any other info I can provide.

Comment: I would find and fix the DNS issue first. Much like Active Directory, FreeIPA depends heavily on DNS.

Comment: Any suggestions on where to begin a DNS fix?

Comment: You didn't really describe that problem, so it wouldn't be possible to even begin to guess.

Comment: Thank you. See https://serverfault.com/q/905013/364829 for my DNS question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to add a record for the domain to our router, which acts as a DNS server for our LAN. So, locally the domain resolves to the IP of the FreeIPA server.

After the above DNS correction I was able to successfully add the Kerberos key to the Samba server.